# Missing purpose strings in Info.plist for sensitive user data access in React Native iOS app

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, plist

I recently submitted my React Native iOS app to the App Store and received review points regarding missing purpose strings in the Info.plist file. The reviews specifically mentioned the following issues:

> **ITMS-90683: Missing purpose string in Info.plist** - The app's code references APIs that access sensitive user data, and the
> **Info.plist** file should include the **NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription** key with a purpose string explaining why the app needs access to the user's location.
>
> **ITMS-90738: Invalid purpose string value** - The **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** key has an empty value in the Info.plist file, which is not allowed. A purpose string should be
> provided to explain why the app needs access to the user's location.

By default, React Native includes the **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** key in the Info.plist file, but it leaves it empty. I understand that it is important to provide a meaningful purpose string, but I have a few questions:

Why does React Native add the **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription** key by default but leave it empty? Should I update this value with a purpose string?

Although my app doesn't directly use location services, I discovered some relevant code related to location permissions in the react-native-permission module, which is a third-party library. Do I still need to add the **NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription** purpose string, even if I'm not using location services in my app?

I want to ensure that my app complies with App Store guidelines and includes the necessary purpose strings. Any advice or guidance on how to address these issues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the message gonna show when asking for user's location info.
You just need to write a simple explain message into the "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description"
open Xcode select project root directory => go to "info" page
and fill in the message to "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description"

Comment: since i was not asking for location access permission now, which string should i need to keep there? so that my there shouldn't be any issues

Comment: this also might cause by enable the background-mode function.
you can turn it off, the detail is in below link.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-background-execution-modes#Specify-the-background-modes-your-app-requires
after you remove the background mode, you can try leave the NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription key with empty value.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-background-execution-modes#Specify-the-background-modes-your-app-requires

Comment: the message is required might due to the package you're using.
In this case you can simply say "We require your location to show you relevant local information and services while you're using the app." in the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription would feet the situation.